# How to Isolate numbers from a column and create 3 new columns?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, findall

I am trying to access a column, filter its numbers and then split in 3 columns. But i have been only getting errors. I am trying this:

```
dsc = df["Descricao"].str.findall("\d+")
dsc

The Output:
0                   []
1       [475, 2000, 3]
2        [65, 2000, 2]
3        [51, 2000, 3]
4       [320, 2000, 3]
             ...      
2344               NaN
2345    [480, 2000, 1]
2346     [32, 2000, 6]
2347    [250, 2000, 1]
2348               NaN
Name: Descricao, Length: 2349, dtype: object
```

Then, I am trying to split and everytime i get this kind of error:

```
df[['Larg','comp', 'qtd']] = dsc.str.split(',',expand=True)
df.head(5)

The Error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15388/2481153233.py in <module>
----> 1 df[['Larg','comp', 'qtd']] = dsc.str.split(',',expand=True)
      2 df.head(5)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   3598             self._setitem_frame(key, value)
   3599         elif isinstance(key, (Series, np.ndarray, list, Index)):
-> 3600             self._setitem_array(key, value)
   3601         elif isinstance(value, DataFrame):
   3602             self._set_item_frame_value(key, value)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _setitem_array(self, key, value)
   3637         else:
   3638             if isinstance(value, DataFrame):
-> 3639                 check_key_length(self.columns, key, value)
   3640                 for k1, k2 in zip(key, value.columns):
   3641                     self[k1] = value[k2]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexers.py in check_key_length(columns, key, value)
    426     if columns.is_unique:
    427         if len(value.columns) != len(key):
--> 428             raise ValueError("Columns must be same length as key")
    429     else:
    430         # Missing keys in columns are represented as -1

ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

I think there is something to do with str.findall generating a list of lists.
Does anybody know how can I solve this?
For information, **all my columns are objects.**

Comment: Looks like split() may not be returning three values for each row. Can you check?

Comment: Would this happen if i have columns without any value on it? If that's the case, i'm going to try filtering those before.

Comment: Yes, I believe it would. Please see my answer to your question for examples.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
dsc = pd.DataFrame(df["Descricao"].str.findall("\d+").tolist(), columns=['Larg','comp', 'qtd'])

df = pd.concat([df, dsc], axis=1)
```

Note that this may not work if there are more than three columns at any point (I assume this will not be the case, given your attempt).

This method came from [here](https://datascienceparichay.com/article/split-pandas-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns/).

Comment: It returned the following error: 

TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, some of the inputs may not have strings that parse to 3 numerical values.

Here is a way to do what the question asks while filling the new columns for any unusual rows with NaNs. If the desired behavior for non-standard rows is different, the logic can be adjusted as needed.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Descricao' : ['', '475,2000,3', '65,2000,2', np.nan, 'abc,def,ghi', '1,2', '1']
})
print(f"\nInput dataframe:\n{df}")

df2 = df["Descricao"].str.findall("\d+").to_frame()
print(f"\nDataframe with lists of 3 where possible:\n{df2}")

df2["Descricao"] = df2.apply(lambda x: 
    x["Descricao"] 
        if (len(x["Descricao"]) if isinstance(x["Descricao"], list) else 0) == 3 else 
    [np.NaN]*3, 
    axis=1)
print(f"\nDataframe with lists include NaNs for incomplete data:\n{df2}")

df2[['Larg','comp', 'qtd']] = pd.DataFrame(df2["Descricao"].tolist(), columns=['Larg','comp', 'qtd'])
df2 = df2.drop(['Descricao'], axis=1)
print(f"\nResult dataframe with NaNs for incomplete inputs:\n{df2}")
```

Sample Output:

```
Input dataframe:
     Descricao
0
1   475,2000,3
2    65,2000,2
3          NaN
4  abc,def,ghi
5          1,2
6            1

Dataframe with lists of 3 where possible:
        Descricao
0              []
1  [475, 2000, 3]
2   [65, 2000, 2]
3             NaN
4              []
5          [1, 2]
6             [1]

Dataframe with lists include NaNs for incomplete data:
         Descricao
0  [nan, nan, nan]
1   [475, 2000, 3]
2    [65, 2000, 2]
3  [nan, nan, nan]
4  [nan, nan, nan]
5  [nan, nan, nan]
6  [nan, nan, nan]

Result dataframe with NaNs for incomplete inputs:
  Larg  comp  qtd
0  NaN   NaN  NaN
1  475  2000    3
2   65  2000    2
3  NaN   NaN  NaN
4  NaN   NaN  NaN
5  NaN   NaN  NaN
6  NaN   NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thank You! I got a part from your solution and developed a new version. But it was an easy start! At the end, my solution was:
```

Comment: It looks like your comment was cut off without showing your solution, but I'm glad my answer was helpful. If you were satisfied, please mark the answer as "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

Thank You all! Following the @constantstranger solution, a part from it solution and developed a new version. But it was an easy start. At the end, my solution was:

```
dsc = ndf['descricao'].str.findall('\d+')        #Separated only the numerical elements
# Created 3 lists for the elements
larg = []
comp = []
qtd = []
for lines in dsc:                    
    for item in enumerate(lines):
        if len(lines) != 3:       #If the length of the elements is not 3, does nothing.
            continue
        if item[0] == 0:
            larg.append(item[1])
        if item[0] == 1:
            comp.append(item[1])
        if item[0] == 2:
            qtd.append(item[1])
#Then i checked for the length of all
print(len(larg), len(comp), len(qtd))

lis = [larg, comp, qtd]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(lis).transpose()
df1.columns = ['larg', 'comp', 'qtd']
df1
```

The Output:

```
    larg    comp    qtd
0   32  2000    6
1   46  1000    1
2   320 100 20
3   220 100 50
4   220 50  30
... ... ... ...
1404    50  2000    1
1405    52  200 2
1406    48  2000    1
1407    325 3000    1
1408    33  2000    2
1409 rows × 3 columns
```

I guess, it's not the ideal solution for big data but it's working for now. I tried the .findall expression with to_frame(), but for some reason every length went to zero.
So, now i'll be looking for a way to optimize.